# Groovy Regular Expressions With Group

Tags: regex, string, groovy, replace

I'm looking for a regular expression in groovy which would match all these and which would have a group matching the specified part in these examples:

1. `priority = "4-Not Prioritized Yet"` **⇒ Group:** *4-Not Prioritized Yet*
2. `priority != "4-Not Prioritized Yet"` **⇒ Group:** *4-Not Prioritized Yet*
3. `priority = High` **⇒ Group:**  *High*
4. `priority = "2-Medium"` **⇒ Group:** *2-Medium*
5. `priority changed` **⇒ No Group**
6. `priority is EMPTY` **⇒ No Group**

I've tried several regex pattern like:

- `/(?i)priority\s*!?=\s*"?([^"]+)"?/`
- `/(?i)priority[^\w]+([^"]+)"?/`
- etc.

but I can't find a pattern that works with all the examples.
So I would like to know what is wrong with my regex and what pattern
would work on all the examples.

What I'm trying to do exactly is something like this:

```
def str = "{project = "TEST"} AND {priority = "4-Not Prioritized Yet"} OR {priority is EMPTY} OR {priority changed} OR {priority = "2-Medium"} OR {priority = "1-High"} OR {priority = "test"} order by priority DESC"
str.replaceAll(/(?i)\{([^\}]+)\}/) {a, b-> 
    if(b.startsWith("priority")) {
        def regex = /(?i)priority([^\w]+)([^"]+)/
        def match = (b =~ regex);
        /* And now I would like to do something like:
           if (match has group) 
               return b.replace(group, "something else")
           else return b */
    } else return b;
}
```

Comment: I think this is close... you will just have to remove the final " if one exists: `priority\s*[=!]+\s*\"(.*)` -Edited Formatting

Comment: No, it is a very unclear question. You have `def str = """{project = "TEST"} AND {priority = "4-Not Prioritized Yet"} OR {priority is EMPTY} OR {priority changed} OR {priority = "2-Medium"} OR {priority = "1-High"} OR {priority = "test"} order by priority DESC"""`, right? Now, what is the expected output? Please provide the expected output [inside a fiddle](http://ideone.com/vLQPRn).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
priority (?:(changed|is EMPTY)|!?= ("?)([^"}]+)\2)
```

Description:

- `priority` - match literal chars (common begin).
- `(?:` - Start of a non-matching group. It is necessary because it contains
  variants.
- `(changed|is EMPTY)` - Variant 1 (first capturing group) - catches both
  cases to be replaced with *No Group*.
- `|` - Variants separator.
- `!?=` - Start of variant 2 - match literal chars (optional `!` and `=`).
- `("?)` - Capturing group 2 - catch quote (if any).
- `([^"}]+)` - Capturing group 3 - the priority value string.
- `\2`- Match what was captured by group 2.
- `)` - End of the non-capturing group.

And below you have an example program, printing both original and replaced string:

```
def str = '{project = "TEST"} AND {priority = "4-Not Prioritized Yet"}\
 OR {priority is EMPTY} OR {priority changed} OR {priority = "2-Medium"}\
 OR {priority = "1-High"} OR {priority = "test"} order by priority DESC'
println str
def res = str.replaceAll(/priority (?:(changed|is EMPTY)|!?= ("?)([^"}]+)\2)/) {
  m, g1, g2, g3 ->
  if (g1?.trim()) {
    return "No Group"
  } else if (g3?.trim()) {
    return "Group: $g3"
  } else {
    return m
  }
}
println res
```

The closure - argument of *replaceAll* has arguments:

- `m` - the whole match,
- `g1` ... `g3` - the content captured by respective capturing groups.

If group 1 catched sometning, we have either of *No Group* cases.

Group 2 catches a quote (if any).

If group 3 catched sometning, we have *Group ...* case.

And one remark about your program: *replaceAll* does not edit the text
"in place". The replaced text is returned as the **result** of this function
and the original string is not changed. So it is necessary to save the
result of this function.